# Delete text contained by bookmarks that are hidden

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a template in which, based on the values of the specific checkboxes (content controls), paragraphs that are selected with bookmarks having the same name as the checkboxes are hidden using the following formula

```
Dim bookmark As String
Dim ctl As ContentControl
For Each ctl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If ctl.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
        If ctl.Checked = False Then
            bookmark = ctl.Tag
            Bookmarks(bookmark).Range.Font.Hidden = True
        Else
            bookmark = "hide_" & ctl.Tag
            Bookmarks(bookmark).Range.Font.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I am trying to strip the document of the paragraphs that are using the above mentioned formula (delete them).
I am trying to strip the document of the hidden paragraphs because I want to number the paragraphs and, without deleting them, the numbering refers to the hidden ones.

Using find and replace with hidden font doesn't help because it's a different type of hidden content. I think the bookmarks are saved in xml code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim CCtrl As ContentControl
For Each CCtrl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
  With CCtrl
    If .Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
      If .Checked = False Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(.Tag).Range.Delete
      End If
    End If
  End With
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I will try the code as soon as possible. I've had the impression that the 'ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmark).Range.Delete' only deletes the bookmark, not the text that's actually bookmarked.

Comment: In that case, you impression was wrong. It is ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmark).Delete that deletes only the bookmark.

Comment: Do you know why the code wouldn't work for the hidden bookmarks? To make it work I have to unhide the bookmarks I want to delete using this code: Bookmarks("name").Range.Font.Hidden = False

Comment: Whether the bookmarked content is hidden or visible is of no consequence - the code I posted will delete the relevant bookmarked content if the checkbox is unchecked.